# Android load HD pngs to ram

Tags: android, image, heap-memory, ram

I'm developing an app and I got several HD Images (PNG Files) throughout the app. To navigate through the app as quickly as possible, I want to load all pictures in RAM and display them when the certain activity starts.
Means each activity has a HD picture.
Since it is quite impossible to load a 32bit HD Image to the RAM of the app, I had to resize them using that bitmap shit of Android. But I don't want to resize them.
Is it possible to load all HD images at the beginning of the app to the RAM? I don't understand why there are HD 3D games like Modern Combat 5 have no problems with that and just take the amount of RAM they need and I can't even load 7 or 8 HD Images at once to my app. Is there a trick? How can I get a Heap large enough for all my stuff to load at once and keep it in RAM while the app is active?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is little point having an image in ram with a resolution higher than the screen which is why you are forced to resize them. Games use OpenGL to render the screen in real time so the memory footprint is less than one might imagine. Remember that you are working on a device with potentially limited memory hence Android forces you to work efficiently - it won't let you take up all the ram you want which would force other apps that are paused to close or prevent another app from starting without your paused app having to be killed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why does an app like Whatsapp gets 80mb of memory on my phone to display chat messages and image/video previews? And I can't load 2 Pictures in HD (my phone has HD resolution) on my phone.

Comment: By the way, the point is, the user is able to scroll over the image if the display has a lower resolution than HD, otherwise the app is not usable since there are Buttons on the images to click on.

Comment: Realize that games employ compressed textures so can't be compared with apps that are using regular Bitmaps. For other apps they are using the techniques referenced by @Dardan. One project you may want to look at if you are trying to do a 'map' like view is https://github.com/moagrius/TileView at the price of tiling your images. Also if the user needs to scroll to hit buttons on smaller screens - reconsider your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recycle() your bitmaps after you complete the work with bitmap, so that will clear your memory :). Read this [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: I don't want to recycle them, since I don't want to clear the memoy of my application at all. I want more than those 16MB in memory for my application. So I can load and keep all the stuff in memory while i use the app. I also don't want to resize them.

Comment: You can use android:largeHeap="true" to request a larger heap size.